# When I set text to anything, all views is hidden

Tags: java, android

I am new to java for android.
Then I attempt to put in textview anything, all views do not be shown.
Main.XML:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNew"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="75px"/>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNew"
        android:text="Click me!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        int randomInt;
        TextView textNew = findViewById(R.id.textNew);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("settings",     Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Button clickButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        textNew.setText("5");
        randomInt = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("setting", "0"));
    }
}
```

I tried to delete textNew.setText("text"). It is helped. But how I can set text!? Me need it!

Comment: Try putting super.onCreate and setContentview first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the button and the Textview before setting the view content

SetContentView(View) sets the activity content to an explicit view.
In your case, you're setting the view to R.layout.main where the Button and the TextView are defined

To fix this move the onCreate and the setContentView before the rest of the code in the onCreate method

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```